# How can I pass a variable from one view to another

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to pass a data from a variable in one view to another without using a form, this is the code:

```
@foreach($ispis as $marka)
    @php
      $query=$marka->MarkaID;
    @endphp
    <a href="/marka"  class="link">
      <div class="column">
        <img src="/logoimg/{{$marka->ImeMarke}}.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </a>
@endforeach
```

I want to take the variable `$query` with the id from the current loop cycle and send/create another view displaying all information from the table with the same id as the $query variable.
Im not sure if i need to make a new controller, what do i need to use in web.php to take the data from the variable and send it from a controller to a new view called "/marka".

Comment: *"I want to take the variable $query with the id from the current loop cycle and send/create another view displaying all information from the table..."* I can't really get what you are trying to do here, can you elaborate or give an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you are tying to make single `marka` `show` page.

In Laravel, generally there are two ways to do that:

```
 1. Without Route Model Binding
 2. With Route Model Binding
```

**routes\web.php**

```
use App\Models\Marka;

// Without Route Model Binding
Route::get("marka/{markaID}", function($markaID) {

   $marka = Marka::findOrFail($markaID);

   return view('marka.show', compact('marka'));

});

// With Route Model Binding
Route::get("marka/{marka}", function(Marka $marka) {

   return view('marka.show', compact('marka'));

})->name('marka.show'); // use name for easiness
```

**resources\views\marka\index.blade.php**

```
@foreach($ispis as $marka)

    {{-- Without Route Model Binding --}}
    <a href="/marka/{{ $marka->MarkaID }}">...</a>

   {{-- With Route Model Binding --}}
    <a href="{{ route('marka.show', ['marka' => $marka]) }}">...</a>

@endforeach
```

**resources\views\marka\show.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Show marka page')

@section('content')

   {{-- Display all information about marka as shown below --}}
   {{ $marka->MarkaID }}
   {{ $marka->ImeMarke }}

@endsection
```

You can also move `$callback` function code in your MarkaController.php

**routes\web.php**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\MarkaController;

Route::get("marka/{markaID}", [MarkaController::class, 'show])->name('marka.show');
```

**App\Http\Controllers\MarkaController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Marka;

class MarkaController extends Controller
{   
    public function show(Marka $marka)
    {
       // With Route Model Binding

         return view('marka.show', compact('marka'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a new view file called something like `marka.blade.php`, and then use the `@include` blade directive.

Example:

```
@include('marka', ['query' => $query])
```

Then `$query` will automatically be available inside your `marka.blade.php` view file because we have explicitly passed it through the `@include` directive.

Or, you can use blade components for this, which is the more modern approach.

Learn here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#components

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding that you want users to click on the link and go to a new view, then you could perhaps pass the $query as a parameter in the href:

```
 @foreach($ispis as $marka)
     @php
       $query=$marka->MarkaID;
     @endphp
     <a href="/marka/{{$query}}"  class="link">
       <div class="column">
         <img src="/logoimg/{{$marka->ImeMarke}}.png" alt="">
       </div>
     </a>
 @endforeach
```

and cater for that in your web.php via:

```
Route::get('/marka/{query}', 'YourController@dosomething');
```

and your controller function would have something like:

```
    public function dosomething($query)
    {
        //use $query
    }
```

(this is just a rough idea but might point you in the right direction)

EDIT: JS Tech said it much better